# Compiling JAR with maven ignoring log4j2 properties when running on different OS

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I have an java app that runs in the background on a server.  The server is running Amazon Linux 2, and my app is using log4j v 2.11.0.  We compile an executable jar on the server using Maven, then execute said jar to run the app.  The issue I'm having is that this app seems to be ignoring certain values specified in my log4j2.xml file (specifically my SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size and my IfLastModified age values).

Maven command used:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF">
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path" >${sys:log_dir}</Property>
    <Property name="log-level" >${sys:log_lvl}</Property>
    <Property name="level-num" >${sys:lvl_num}</Property>
    <Property name="log-project-name">${sys:log_name}</Property>
    <Property name="log-pattern">%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t|%c{1}] %m\n</Property>
    <Property name="rollover-strategy-max">7</Property>
    <Property name="rolling-size-based">5 KB</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>

<RollingFile name="logFile" fileName="${log-path}/${log-project-name}-logger.log" filePattern="${log-path}/${log-project-name}-debug-%d-%i.log.zip">
    <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>${log-pattern}</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${rolling-size-based}" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${rollover-strategy-max}">
        <Delete basePath="${log-path}" maxDepth="1">
            <IfFileName regex="foobar-*.log.zip" />
            <IfLastModified age="21D" />
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>

</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <logger name="io.switchfour" level="${log-level}" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="logFile" level="${log-level}" />
    </logger>
</Loggers>
</configuration>
```

Here are my maven dependencies I'm using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

With this configuration, I have an active logging file called foobar-logger.log, which becomes foobar-debug-2018-08-13-1.log.zip when it gets rolled over. This is what I expect.  However, I'd also expect that any archived log file older than 21 days would get deleted.  But no files ever get deleted.  I've tried setting the chmod permissions to 777 for some of the files, which didn't do anything.  I've also tried alternating between using regex and glob in my IfFileName tag (which properly returns the list of archived log files via bash's ls) as well as "21D" and "21d" for my age.  I've been searching for solutions for several days now, but no matter what I try, it never seems to delete any old files.  Some of these files are 2+ months old.  I'm not sure if this is related, but the size limit (5 KB) often seems to get ignored, but not always. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm not certain that this was the cause of my issue, but it seems like compiling the jar on my local computer (running OSX 10.13.6) instead of compiling it on the server (running Amazon Linux 2) was causing the age value in my log4j2.xml file to get ignored.  Could someone shed some light on the affects (if any) of compiling a jar on different OSs via the following maven command:

mvn clean compile assembly:single

Answer (score 0):

I got the old rolled over log files to delete when I compiled the jar on the server instead of compiling it in IntelliJ and FTPing it to the server.  I'm not sure why compiling the jar on the server made a difference.  If anyone has any insight to share regarding this, please do so.  My server is running Amazon Linux 2 while my computer is running OSX 10.13.6.

I used the following maven command to compile the jar:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

I also changed

```
<IfFileName regex="foobar-*.log.zip" />
<IfLastModified age="21D" />
```

to

```
<IfFileName glob="foobar-*.log.zip" />
<IfLastModified age="21d" />
```